# Is there a Windows command line with smart bash-like autocompletions / command history?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash

I recently started using bash, and discovered some really wonderful features (not necessarily come out of the box, but can be configured):

- Up/down arrows support partial completion: Type "git ", press the UP arrow, and you'll get to browse through the recent commands that starts with "git " (even in previous sessions!)
- Ctrl-R will search your command history (called reversed-i-search for some reason)
- Many, many more I'm not aware of, I'm sure.

Is there a good cmd.exe alternative for Windows that supports such features? I've browsed through the top answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/87441/alternative-windows-command-shell-and-console), but didn't find if any of the popular alternatives support it.

Comment: Have you ever tried F7 in the command prompt?

Comment: I have not. And the first Google result (from 2005 no less!) is a Coding Horror!

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/stupid-command-prompt-tricks.html

Now just answer the other part of my question, and I'll be even more thrilled.

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows users generally use what the system comes with, and there's no popular cmd.exe replacement. Cygwin is widely used as a Linux "emulator" for Windows, you might give it a try. @William: nice didn't know that, but have you ever tried *bash*? Bash remembers commands of old sessions, not only current session. And also filters results as ripper234 states, not to talk about converting links into valid URLs, scrolling with mouse on terminal applications and a long list... And btw, why you still cannot horizontally resize the command prompt window? This will always puzzle me...

Comment: Two popular `cmd` replacements are discussed both below (by `paradroid` and `RedGrittyBrick`) and in the answers hyperlinked-to above, and your latter question is based upon an observably incorrect premise.  I just used the mouse to horizontally resize a console window myself.

Answer (score 24):

Download and install the [Powershell 2.0 console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930/en-us) (if you are using Windows 7, it is already installed).

It supports all the legacy commands as well as alias, macros and more...

Here are some [basic tips](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff678293.aspx).

[image: power-shell-dialog]

`get-history:` Displays a list of previously entered commands.

`invoke-history 35:` Executes command #35 in the *get-history* list

<kbd>`</kbd>:Press the backward apostrophe key to insert a line break or as an >escape character to make a literal character. You can also break a line at the pipe (|) character.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Space+<kbd>E</kbd>: Displays an editing shortcut menu with *Mark, Copy, Paste, Select All, Scroll, and Find* options. You can then press <kbd>K</kbd> for Mark, <kbd>Y</kbd> for Copy, <kbd>P</kbd> for Paste, <kbd>S</kbd> for Select All, <kbd>L</kbd> to scroll through the screen buffer, or <kbd>F</kbd> to search for text in the screen buffer. To copy the screen buffer to the Clipboard, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Space+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Space+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>: Clears the command history.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: Break out of the subprompt or terminate execution.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> : Delete all the characters in the line **after** the cursor.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> || <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> :  Move left or right one word at a time.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>: Pause||resume the display of output.

<kbd>Esc</kbd> Clear the current line.

<kbd>F1</kbd> Moves the cursor one character to the right on the command line. At the end of the line, inserts one character from the text of your last command.

<kbd>F2</kbd> Creates a new command line by copying your last command line up to the character you type.

<kbd>F3</kbd> Completes the command line with the content from your last command line, starting from the current cursor position to the end of the line.

<kbd>F4</kbd> Deletes characters from your current command line, starting from the current cursor position up to the character you type.

<kbd>F5</kbd> Scans backward through your command history.

<kbd>F7</kbd>: Similar to `get-history`. Displays a pop-up window with your command history and allows you to select a command. Use the arrow keys to scroll through the list. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select a command to run, or press the <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> to place the text on the command line.

<kbd>F8</kbd> Uses text you’ve entered to scan backward through your command history for commands that match the text you’ve typed so far on the command line.

<kbd>F9</kbd> Runs a specific numbered command from your command history. Command numbers are listed when you press <kbd>F7</kbd> or `get-history`.

<kbd>Page Up</kbd> / <kbd>Page Down</kbd>: Gets the **first/last** command in the command history.

Right-click If QuickEdit is disabled, displays an editing shortcut menu with Mark, Copy, Paste, Select All, Scroll, and Find options. To copy the screen buffer to the Clipboard, right-click, choose Select, and then press Enter.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Press the Tab key or press Shift+Tab to access the tab expansion function, which include folder or filename autocompletion.

Comment: Does it support partial history search?

Comment: Yes, type the string you want to search and hit F8.

Comment: That's a very comprehensive overview of PowerShell keyboard controls.

Comment: I'll scrape up a list of must have Powershell modules later. . .

Comment: @surfasb: You should include PowerTab, as it is relevant for this answer.  Tabbing with it is like IntelliSense.

Comment: I just got around to trying it - I'm not sure how it works exactly. F8  doesn't work the way I expect - the order of the commands shown is weird. Also, it's annoying that it's F8 and not UP/DOWN arrows - I'd simply like the UP arrow to go one command back in the history filtered by the prefix I entered, and DOWN to do the opposite.

Comment: F8 matches the most recent one based on the text prefix. Then hitting F8 scrolls through those results. It's like hitting F3 in a word processor.

Comment: @ripper234: If you do not like PowerShell, why don't you try TCC/LE, as I mentioned in my answer.  It does exactly what you describe.

Comment: FWIW, *all* keyboard shortcuts listed here are *not* PowerShell-specific; rather they are built into the Windows console which both cmd.exe and PowerShell share. PowerShell is merely a *shell*, a command interpreter - it does not concern itself with how the commands are input.

Comment: very nice ! and its preinstalled on Win 7 ! superb

Comment: You can use F8 to search even in normal cmd.exe

Answer (score 16):

You don't need to replace the Command Prompt!  Windows has many of these features built into the Command Prompt, such as:

- Command history: <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd>
- Add 1 letter at a time from the previous command: <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Auto completion of directories and filenames: <kbd>Tab</kbd>

There are even more tricks, but you will need to look further on Google as I couldnt find a website with a comprehensive list.

Answer (score 13):

[Clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) extends the Windows command line and adds the following features

- Powerful Bash-like line editing from GNU's Readline library
- Superior path completion (TAB)
- Paste from clipboard (Ctrl-V)
- Support for the completion of executables/commands, and environment variables
- Undo/Redo (Ctrl-_ or Ctrl-X, Ctrl-U) Improved command line history. Persists across sessions
- Searchable (Ctrl-R and Ctrl-S). History expansion (e.g. !!, !, and !$). Scriptable completion using Lua.

Comment: Perfect. It makes cmd.exe so much more useful.

Answer (score 5):

[Win-Bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/)?

> A stand-alone bash for Windows
>
> win-bash is a windows port of the famous GNU bash (see GNU Bash homepage).
>
> Unlike other bash ports for windows (e.g. the cygwin bash), the win-bash needs no special environment or DLLs. There is just one binary and that's it.

I'm not sure how functional and reliable this is.

---

There is also jpsoftware's [take command](http://jpsoft.com/) - but, oops, that was mentioned in the other Q you mentioned, so presumably doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Actually, Take Command **does** do what xe wants.  It has [global command history](http://jpsoft.com./help/localandglobal.htm) that can be remembered even when no command interpreter is running.  It has [history list filtering and editing](http://jpsoft.com./help/histwin.htm).  My guess is that "the top answers" does not stretch to answer #5. ☺

Comment: @JdeBP - Take Command is about #12 on the list.

Comment: SuperUser is listing it as the fifth answer when viewed here.

Comment: You can sort answers by "active", "oldest" or "votes". By "votes" is default  and SuperUser then seems to randomise answers with equal votes - I find refreshing the page changes the order..

Comment: I'm very reluctant to start using a software product that had its latest release in 2003.

Comment: @ripper234: What are you talking about?  Win-Bash was updated last March.

Comment: @paranoid - Googling for winbash and going to the download page got me to this page, which says 2003 - http://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/files/bash_nt/bash_nt-1.14.2%20%28outdated%20-%20use%20win-bash%20releases%29/

Comment: That page confirms what paradroid says.  Read it _properly_.  And you didn't need to Google for anything.  RedGrittyBrick **gave** the hyperlink in xyr answer.

Answer (score 3):

[**Take Command**](http://jpsoft.com/take_command_windows_scripting.html) has already been mentioned, but [**TCC/LE**](http://jpsoft.com/tccle_cmd_replacement.html) (a subset) is a *free* `CMD` replacement with a lot more features, commands and customisability.  It goes some way towards giving a bash-like experience, as far as keyboard shortcuts, aliases and colouring goes.

It can do the few things you mention, including partial history completion with `Up/Down` arrows.  `CTRL-B` repeats path from the previous command.  Try typing `option` to see a whole load of options.

`TCC/LE` also works very nicely within [**Console2**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

Also, you can of course use bash on Windows with [**Cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The open-source [PyCmd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pycmd/) Command Prompt extension does most of what you ask for.

Its purpose is to emulate a few power features of UNIX shells (decent Tab-completion, persistent history, etc.).

[image]